# Excel 2010 PivotTable -- cannot change value in any cell "cannot change this part of a pivottable report"

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Does anyone know how to enable editing in a cell in a PivotTable?  I need to be able to type an order quantity into cells in the table but I get the error "Cannot change this part of a PivotTable report".

any help?  thanks!

Comment: hi @pnuts -- I can't add the data in because I don't have it.  The reason the cell needs to be able to be edited is so the user can enter in the future order quantity for the upcoming year.  Basically the PT show what they GOT last year and the user needs to be able to enter in the new quantity to be ordered for the upcoming year.  It's an order rebooking PT so customers can say what they want to rebook for the upcoming year based on what they got last year.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this pivot table been created in an older version of Excel, and you are now working in a newer version of Excel? If so, you may have to convert, or open, the pivot table in a previous or older format.

Comment: It's a PivotTable I just created, in 2010.

Comment: Then it is as @pnuts says...need to add to raw data first which is the source of data you used to construct the pivot table.

Comment: thanks, but that won't work. :(  the PT that I create is ordered quantities from previous shipments and I need to be able to change/add quanties for the upcoming year, so I do not have that data available when I create the PT.  Actually, the customer that the order is for is the one that will be entering in the new quantities.  I hope this clarifies?